# return type defaults to 'int' in C code

Tags: c

Contents of somefile.h

```
#ifndef __SOMEFILE_H
#define __SOMEFILE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct _table_t table_t;

struct _table_t
{
     void (*somefunction1)();
     void (*somefunction2)(int a);
     void (*somefunction3)(int a, int *b);
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
} 
#endif
#endif <-- I am getting the error here
```

---

somefile.h is included in both .cpp and .c files. When this project is build on Linux, I am getting the following error:

> error: return type defaults to 'int'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `__SOMEFILE_H`, such names are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @Daniel, it is actually a different name, I just posted this here for simplicity.

Comment: Please post your actual header file, this one does not reflect your issue

Comment: It may or may not be related, but functions that take no parameters should use an explicit '`void`' in the parameter list.  Add the missing '`void`' to the definition of `somefunction1` and see if anything changes.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ \[-Wreturn-type\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373538/warning-return-type-defaults-to-int-wreturn-type)

Answer (score 3):

You have a function that does not have return type defined.  Look for something like

```
Foo(void);
```

or

```
Foo(void) {
  printf("foo you too");
}
```

Comment: @RRR If this declaration is the first thing after `#include` your compiler may get confused. What compiler are you using? Can you provide both `.c` and `.h` file so we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: I don't get this error when I compile it on windows machine, I see it only when I build it on Linux.

Comment: @RRR, depending on warning levels and such, you may not get an error.  Like the error says, if you don't give a return type it will default to int.  It would probably help to include both .h and .c like Banthar said, and definitely the exact .h file.